# Variable Variable wont work with array

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a variable variable, but it wont work when I use it in the code below.

I keep getting:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: C in C:\web\apache\htdocs\cats-test.php on line 8
```

This only wont work when used with an array. Can you help?

```
$Consumer = array(
"a" => "Apparel",
"b" => "Books & Stationary",
);
$cat = "Consumer";

echo $$cat['a']; //I'm trying to make this $Consumer['a'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing an array key in a variable variable, enclose the variable in `{}` to be certain that PHP expands the correct set of characters (`$cat`) as a variable.

```
echo ${$cat}['a'];
// Apparel
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ${$cat}['a'];
```

It's ambiguous whether you mean `$$cat ['a']` or `$ $cat['a']`. Use brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of operator priorities. `${$cat}['a']` should work better.